# Не работает в gulp browser-sync

Tags: gulp, browsersync, gulp-sass, gulp-watch

Установил плагин для gulp browser-sync, настроил чтобы он обновлял браузер когда я изменю html и sass, но он почему-то в консоли пишет что страница обновлена, хотя по факту она не обновляется...

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
minCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();


gulp.task('minCSS', function(){
  gulp.src('app/css/*.css')
    .pipe(minCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('general/css'))
});


gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src('app/sass/*.sass')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('general/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());

});

gulp.task('server', ['sass'], function(){
  browserSync.init({
      server: "app/"
  });

  gulp.watch('app/sass/*.sass', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('app/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

P.s. Что я сделал не правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас перезагрузки не происходит нужно [прописать reload](https://browsersync.io/docs/api#api-reload):

```
.pipe(browserSync.reload());
```

Answer (score 0):

Для свежих версий browser-sync получаем сообщение об ошибке

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

поэтому в конфиге нужно писать

```
.pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
```

Это изменение для версий browser-sync более 2.6

Или же переключаться на использование нового метода  `.stream()`

[Соответствующий тикет на github разработчиков](https://github.com/Browsersync/browser-sync/issues/573)